# Flutter: Riverpod rebuild all elements in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider, riverpod

Recently I started to learn riverpod and provider as state management method. Therefore I wanted to rebuild my current application.

**My Problem**

In my application I have a list (ListView.builder) which displays multiple cards. When a card is clicked (GestureDetector), it should be flipped. This worked with the previous state management (setState()) without any problems. When using riverpod, all cards in the ListView are now flipped when clicking on one card.

Here is my code:

**Provider**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

@immutable
class TestMovieCard {
  const TestMovieCard({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String id;
  final String title;
}

class MoviesNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TestMovieCard>> {
  MoviesNotifier()
      : super([
          const TestMovieCard(id: "1", title: "Im Westen nichts Neues"),
          const TestMovieCard(
              id: "2", title: "Star Wars Das Erwachen der Macht")
        ]);

  double _flipAngle = 0;
  double get flipAngle => _flipAngle;

  void flipMovieCard() {
    _flipAngle = (_flipAngle + pi) % (2 * pi);
    state = [...state];
  }

  bool checkIfCardIsFront(double animationValue) {
    if (animationValue >= (pi / 2)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

final movieCardProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MoviesNotifier, List<TestMovieCard>>((ref) {
  return MoviesNotifier();
});
```

**Widget**

```
class Test extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    List<TestMovieCard> movieCards = ref.watch(movieCardProvider);

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: size.height * 0.05,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: TabBarView(children: [
                        MediaQuery.removePadding(
                            removeTop: true,
                            context: context,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: movieCards.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    // key: Key(movieCards[widget.listIndex].id),
                                    onTap: () {
                                      ref
                                          .watch(movieCardProvider.notifier)
                                          .flipMovieCard();
                                    },
                                    child: TweenAnimationBuilder(
                                        tween: Tween<double>(
                                            begin: 0,
                                            end: ref
                                                .watch(
                                                    movieCardProvider.notifier)
                                                .flipAngle),
                                        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            double val, __) {
                                          return (Transform(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              transform: Matrix4.identity()
                                                ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                                                ..rotateY(val),
                                              child: ref
                                                      .watch(movieCardProvider
                                                          .notifier)
                                                      .checkIfCardIsFront(val)
                                                  ? Card(
                                                      elevation: 5,
                                                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                          borderRadius:
                                                              BorderRadius.all(
                                                                  Radius.circular(
                                                                      20.0))),
                                                      child: Container(
                                                          height: size.height *
                                                              0.25,
                                                          decoration:
                                                              const BoxDecoration(
                                                            borderRadius:
                                                                BorderRadius.all(
                                                                    Radius.circular(
                                                                        20.0)),
                                                          ),
                                                          child: const Center(
                                                            child:
                                                                Text("Front"),
                                                          )))
                                                  : Transform(
                                                      alignment:
                                                          Alignment.center,
                                                      transform:
                                                          Matrix4.identity()
                                                            ..rotateY(pi),
                                                      child: Card(
                                                          elevation: 5,
                                                          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius
                                                                  .all(Radius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          20.0))),
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            height:
                                                                size.height *
                                                                    0.25,
                                                            width:
                                                                double.infinity,
                                                            decoration:
                                                                const BoxDecoration(
                                                              borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .all(
                                                                Radius.circular(
                                                                    20.0),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                            child: const Center(
                                                              child:
                                                                  Text("Back"),
                                                            ),
                                                          )),
                                                    )));
                                        }),
                                  );
                                })),
                        Placeholder()
                      ])),
                )
              ],
            )),
        bottomNavigationBar: const CustomBottomNavigationBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope i made my point clear. Thank you in advance.

I have already tried to implement the consumer in several places, but the state of all list items is always reloaded.

---

**EDIT: New Provider code based on the help of Axel**

```
@immutable
class TestMovieCard {
  TestMovieCard({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String id;
  final String title;
  double flipAngle = 0;

  void flip() {
    flipAngle = (flipAngle + pi) % (2 * pi);
  }
}

class MoviesNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<TestMovieCard>> {
  MoviesNotifier()
      : super([
          TestMovieCard(id: "1", title: "Im Westen nichts Neues"),
          TestMovieCard(
            id: "2",
            title: "Star Wars Das Erwachen der Macht",
          )
        ]);

  void flipMovieCard(String idToFlip) {
    state = [
      ...state.where((x) => x.id != idToFlip),
      ...state.where((x) => x.id == idToFlip).flip()
    ];
  }

  bool checkIfCardIsFront(double animationValue) {
    if (animationValue >= (pi / 2)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}

final movieCardProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<MoviesNotifier, List<TestMovieCard>>((ref) {
  return MoviesNotifier();
});
```

Comment: It's because you are using same provider for all your cards. There should be some way to distinguish the currently selected card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the `_flipAngle` attribute in your `TestMovieCard` so you can distinguish which cards must be flipped and which not.

Then, once you call `flipMovieCard`, pass the card index to flip only the selected card.
The code should be something like:

```
  void flipMovieCard(int index) {
    state[index].flipAngle = (state[index].flipAngle + pi) % (2 * pi);
  }
```

**Edit post OP's comment:**

The reason why the widget is not rebuilding automatically is because you need to recreate the entire list.

You could implement a `flip` method in the `TestMovieCard` class and then do this:

```
TestMovieCard flippedCard = state.where((x) => x.id == idToFlip).first;
flippedCard.flip();
state = [...state.where((x) => x.id != idToFlip), flippedCard];
```

Instead of:

```
state[index].flipAngle = (state[index].flipAngle + pi) % (2 * pi);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that has already helped me a lot and also theoretically brings exactly what I want. I have also adjusted the end point of the tween to movieCards[index].flipAngle. The problem now is that when clicking on the card no rebuild is done but the card is only flipped when the application is reloaded. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain why the widget is not rebuilding

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work yet. I cannot call the flip function that I have now created in my TestMovieCard class via "...state.where((x) => x.id == idToFlip).flip()". I have added the actual provider code to my question.

Comment: Updated the answer again. Should work now

Comment: This works perfectly. However, this also changes the sorting in the list, because the "flippedCard" is always set to the last position. Is there also a solution for this?

Comment: nvm i think i worked it out by myself. Thank you alot. You really saved me there. I thought i will never fix this. Thanks!